# JQuery draggable google map

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a div overlay with a gmap on it and have used a jquery plugin to make it draggable
but when i try to use the pull and drag function on the map the whole div move. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Using the Google Maps API, you should automatically be given a draggable, zoomable, and fully customizable map by default, similar to using it on their site. We'd need to see your code.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate around the map, or are you trying to move the map around on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the google map in another div and assign it a handle, here is the code and a working example.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="draggable">
    <div id="handle">Handle</div>
    <iframe width="700px" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=108+S+4th+St,+Cabot,+AR+72023,+USA&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=34.983948,-92.014875&amp;spn=0.012273,0.027122&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=addr&amp;om=1&amp;output=embed&amp;s=AARTsJrKwkyz-ofBV3q5yi6SmToKlUCe8Q" style="height: 522px"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.draggable').draggable({'handle' : '#handle'});
});
```

**Example :**

http://jsfiddle.net/semTg/